# Embeddings of Coxeter Groups of Rank $3$ into $\text{SO}(3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, coxeter-groups

Let $W = \langle x_1, x_2, x_3 \;|\; (x_ix_j)^{m_{ij}} \rangle$ be an irreducible Coxeter group, i.e., the graph with vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and edges between all pairs $(v_i, v_j)$ with $m_{ij} \ne 2$, is connected.

Does there always exist a faithful representation $\rho: W \rightarrow \text{SO}(3, \mathbb{R})$? If not, can you find a criterion on $W$ (except for that the reflection representation be positive definite) for which there does exist such a representation?

Comment: Isn’t the “reflection representation” exactly such a thing? Am I not understanding your question?

Comment: The reflection representation is a faithful representation into O(3), but not into SO(3) since the generators of W get mapped to reflections, which are not orientation preserving.

Comment: Ah, I see, the $SO$ versus $O$ distinction is part of the point...